# gcc compile expected ‘)’ before ‘;’ token，error: expected expression before ‘}’ token }

Tags: c, linux, gcc, pthreads

I copy this code from a Linux pthread pdf file. This code descript customer and producer problem, the demo use linkedlist to achieve this model.
 When i compile by gcc, show this error, how can i fix it? I try to modify if( -> if() or   pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx); ->   pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx)); add or delete } before 36 line, but not work.

```
    #include <pthread.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <malloc.h>

    static pthread_mutex_t mtx = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
    static pthread_cond_t cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

    struct node {
        int n_number;
        struct node *n_next;
    } *head = NULL;

    static void cleanup_handler(void *arg)
    {
        printf("Cleanup handler of second thread\n");
        free(arg);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
    }

    static void *thread_func(void *arg)   // customer
    {
        struct node *p = NULL;
        pthread_cleanup_push(cleanup_handler, p);
        while (1)
        {
        if(
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
        while (head == NULL || (flag=0)){ pthread_cond_wait(&cond,&mtx);}
        p = head;
        head = head->n_next;
        printf("Got %d from front of queue\n", p->n_number);
        free(p);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
        else
        }

        pthread_exit(NULL);
        pthread_cleanup_pop(0); // must be put in last line 
    }

    int main(void)
    {
        pthread_t tid;
        int i;
        struct node *p;
        pthread_create(&tid, NULL, thread_func, NULL);
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)  // producer
        {
        p = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        p->n_number = i;
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);// because head is share，visit share data must
 be add lock/mutex
        p->n_next = head;
        head = p;
        pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
        sleep(1);
        }
        printf("thread 1 wanna end the line.So cancel thread 2.\n");
        pthread_cancel(tid);
        pthread_join(tid, NULL);
        printf("All done------exiting\n");
        return 0;
    }



$gcc -o producer_customer_linkedlist producer_customer_linkedlist.c -lpthread
producer_customer_linkedlist.c: In function ‘thread_func’:
producer_customer_linkedlist.c:28:26: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘;’ token
  pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
                          ^
producer_customer_linkedlist.c:36:2: error: expected expression before ‘}’ token
  }
  ^
```

Comment: `if(
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);` what do you want to do here??

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre that is one _bad-a**_ `if` statement. ;)

Comment: one bad a** else: `else
        }` seriously ??

Comment: there are so many wrong things in this code, I'd rather tell you to make the changes you think you should make and then try asking again

Comment: I also think this code have many wrong, and guess the pdf file code is wrong which i refer to.

Comment: @SouravGhosh I guess the condition is completely missing in the code.

Comment: Firstly you should check if there are no differences between PDF code and the code you've pasted here ;)

Comment: If you used a sane coding style, you wouldn't get these kind of errors. This code is a complete mess.

Comment: @KarolT. I have check PDF code and the code i have pasted there, it is same. Other code have worked, but this code can not work and i do not know how to fix, so i pasted here.

Comment: What is the URL of the PDF file?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick   No URL of the PDF file, it is a linux c/c++ programmer institution data, i think the staff/teacher edit error.  Extra add If( ...    else variable in this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have lot of problems with your code. You need to understand what compilers reports about or else it's not that easy to fix the code. I suggest you to start with learning basics about C.

**Error from GCC compiler:**

```
xx.c: In function ‘thread_func’:
xx.c:28:29: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘;’ token
     pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
                             ^
xx.c:36:5: error: expected expression before ‘}’ token
     }
     ^
xx.c: In function ‘main’:
xx.c:53:1: error: unknown type name ‘be’
 be add lock/mutex
 ^
xx.c:53:8: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘lock’
 be add lock/mutex
        ^
```

It's fairly easy to follow the error and fix the problem. I suggest you to start learning how to debug your program.

1. Syntax error on else
2. The flag is not set by anyone, usage of that variable is futile. I just removed it.

Some useful links to learn about pthreads:

1. [Pthreads examples.](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15492-f07/www/pthreads.html)
2. [Understanding GCC compiler error and warnings](http://www.it.uc3m.es/abel/as/DSP/L2/CCErrors_en.html).

---

**Corrected Code**

In the below code, I just corrected the compiler errors and removed the unused variable in order to work.

What I learned from your question, you used the Linux book example, copied and ran in your editor, and you ended up in the problems, So I suggest you to learn how basic C syntax and understand GCC warning and errors.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

static pthread_mutex_t mtx = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
static pthread_cond_t cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

struct node {
    int n_number;
    struct node *n_next;
} *head = NULL;

static void cleanup_handler(void *arg)
{
    printf("Cleanup handler of second thread\n");
    free(arg);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
}

static void *thread_func(void *arg)   // customer
{
    struct node *p = NULL;

    pthread_cleanup_push(cleanup_handler, p);
    while (1)
    {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
    while (head == NULL){
      pthread_cond_wait(&cond,&mtx);
    }
    p = head;
    head = head->n_next;
    printf("Got %d from front of queue\n", p->n_number);
    free(p);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
    }

    pthread_exit(NULL);
    pthread_cleanup_pop(0); // must be put in last line
}

int main(void)
{
    pthread_t tid;
    int i;
    struct node *p;
    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, thread_func, NULL);
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)  // producer
    {
    p = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    p->n_number = i;
    // because head is share，visit share data must be add lock/mutex
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
    p->n_next = head;
    head = p;
    pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
    sleep(1);
    }
    printf("thread 1 wanna end the line.So cancel thread 2.\n");
    pthread_cancel(tid);
    pthread_join(tid, NULL);
    printf("All done------exiting\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that code is right? The `if` statement doesn't look right still - I'd have expected the code up to the mutex unlock to be in a block.

Comment: @LethalProgrammer  I used the Linux book example, copied in sublime editor and compiler by gcc. Though the run result to understand linux book example. But some example in the book have error and not work, i do not know how to fix it.  I also think i should learn/review how basic C syntax and debug programm. Thank you for  your help and advise.

Comment: @ChrisTurner thanks for pointing out, I missed to remove that if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Corrent code from the word file. The PDF code from the book is a training institution data, i think staff/teacher edit error.

```
#include <pthread.h> 
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>    // 1.work on Linux  
                       // 2. error on OS X,fatal error:'malloc.h' file not 
                       //   found #include <malloc.h> ^~~~~~~~~~1 error 
                       // generated.

#include <stdlib.h>    // work on OS X      

static pthread_mutex_t mtx = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
static pthread_cond_t cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
struct node {
        int n_number;
        struct node *n_next;
} *head = NULL;

static void cleanup_handler(void *arg)
{
    printf("Cleanup handler of second thread\n");
    free(arg);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
}

static void *thread_func(void *arg)// customer
{
    struct node *p = NULL;
    pthread_cleanup_push(cleanup_handler, p);
    while (1)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
        while (head == NULL){ 
            pthread_cond_wait(&cond,&mtx);
      }
        p = head;
        head = head->n_next;
        printf("Got %d from front of queue\n", p->n_number);
        free(p);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
    pthread_cleanup_pop(0);   //must be put in last line 
}
int main(void)
{
    pthread_t tid;
    int i;
    struct node *p;
    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, thread_func, NULL);
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) // producer
    {
            p = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            p->n_number = i;
            pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);// because head is share，visit share data
                                     // must be add lock/muck
            p->n_next = head;
            head = p;
            pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
            sleep(1);
    }
    printf("thread 1 wanna end the line.So cancel thread 2.\n");
    pthread_cancel(tid);
    pthread_join(tid, NULL);
    printf("All done------exiting\n");
    return 0;
}
```